# Shell script works when run manually, fails if run by a launch agent

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, launch-agent

I have a script that I am trying to get to run at login. The script is meant to clear the contents of the Desktop, Documents, and Downloads folders.

I'm using a launch agent to trigger the script to run at load. When I run the script manually, everything functions as expected. All directories are cleared, just as they should be.

However, when that same script is triggered by a Launch Agent, stderr reports "no matches found: /Users/jdoe/Desktop/*" and stdout reports "Checking /Users/jdoe/Desktop". None of the other directories are even checked.

```
#!/bin/zsh

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
Removes files from the specified directories
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
Define Variables

userName="jdoe"
directories=("Desktop" "Documents" "Downloads")
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
Define functions

removeFiles() {
    local folder="/Users/$userName/$dir"
    for file in "$folder"/*
    do
    echo "Removing $file"
    /bin/rm -rf "$file"
    done
}

clearFiles() {
    date
    for dir in "${directories[@]}"
    do
    echo "Checking folder $dir"
    removeFiles
    done
}

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# main

clearFiles

exit 0
```

Here is the Launch Agent which is saved at /Users/jdoe/Library/LaunchAgents/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>domain.label</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/bin/zsh</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/PATH/TO/script.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/PATH/TO/domain.label.filename.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/PATH/TO/domain.label.filename.stdout</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've also tried variations of the plist. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>domain.label</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/PATH/TO/script.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/PATH/TO/domain.label.filename.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/PATH/TO/domain.label.filename.stdout</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When the script is created the folowing function sets it's permissions:

```
setScriptPermissions() {
    chown jdoe ${script}
    chmod 755 ${script}
}
```

When the launch agent is created:

```
setAgentPermissions() {
    chown jdoe "$plist"
    chmod 644 "$plist"
}
```

Comment: Remember, Apple has its own reinforcement on top of the basic UNIX permissions model. When you run a script from a terminal, it inherits approvals you granted that terminal (to access your Desktop directory, f/e).

Comment: You didn't show us the right script. We see `echo "Checking folder $dir"` in the script, but the message you show is `"Checking /Users/jdoe/Desktop"`

Comment: You're probably running into macOS' privacy protection system ("Transparency, Consent, and Control" -- TCC), which restricts access to many user folders. You have to find a way to grant the script access to your Documents etc folders. See ["How to run a LaunchAgent that runs a script which causes failures because of System Integrity Protection"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338213/how-to-run-a-launchagent-that-runs-a-script-which-causes-failures-because-of-sys).

Comment: Thank you @GordonDavisson. Looks like you're correct. Created a PPPC profile that granted zsh access to each directory. Worked like a charm. Looks like [the good ol' days](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxOIebkmrqs) are behind us.

Answer (score 0):

Had to create a pppc profile that granted access to each folder to zsh.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. On a style note, lines of `# # # ....` makes things a bit hard to read. If you want a comment to stand out, include a `## comment` or for even more impact include a single `#` above and below the `##` line. But generally, *less-is-more* where fluff is concerned. Good luck with your scripting.